# VirtualBox File Conversion Error: VMDK to VDI Clonehd Error

Tags: virtualbox

I'm trying to convert VMDK to VDI by clonehd, and I'm getting the following errors:

> "VBoxManage.exe: error: Invalid medium storage format '.vdi'"

Answer (score 0):

Try to run

`"C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe" clonehd "VMHDD.vmdk" "VMHDD.vdi" --format vdi`